# Mongodb connection string format when connecting to mongos

Tags: mongodb

When connecting to a db using the mongodb node driver, [you can specify various options which are arranged in four hashes](http://mongodb.github.io/node-mongodb-native/driver-articles/mongoclient.html#mongoclient-connect-options):

> db {Object, default: null} a hash off options to set on the db object,
>
> server {Object, default: null} a hash off options to set on the server objects, see Server constructor**
>
> replSet {Object, default: null} a hash off options to set on the replSet object, see ReplSet constructor**
>
> mongos {Object, default: null} a hash off options to set on the mongos object, see Mongos constructor**

My question is, **When connecting to a local mongos (shard router) instance, are the `server` options superfluous? Or should a combination of `server` and `mongos` options be used?**

I wasn't able to clearly ascertain this from the documentation, and the options in the mongos hash are quite limited.

EDIT: The options format I'm using (via mongoose) is:

```
options = {
      server:{
            ...
      }
      mongos:{
            ...
      }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The point in the documentation you refer to actually states the limitation of the options you can pass in using the "url" connection string format, where the "options" are included in that "url" passed to the MongoClient constructor.

What this actually means is that if you need "more control" than what is offered by the available connection string options then you would use the `Server` object instead to directly specify or otherwise include options that were not supported:

For example:

```
var mongoClient = MongoClient.connect(
    new Server( "localhost", 27017 ),
    { 
       socketOptions: {
           keepAlive: 1
       }
    }
);

mongoClient.open(function(err,mongoClient) {
    // etc.
```

Or even with an array of mongos instances as `Server` objects if you want several routers available for possible use by the application.

So it is not as if the options are not supported when connecting to a mongos instance, but that some of the options that apply are not supported when using the connection string format.

Comment: Sorry, yes I may I have used the wrong terminology - I understand that these are options that can't be controlled by the standard URI options.  But what I really want to know is - can the server and mongos options be used together?  Or do the server options get ignored when connecting to a mongos instance?

Comment: BTW - I'm not using mongoClient directly - we're using a combination of mongoskin and mongoose.  I've added an example of the format we are using. Perhaps this wasn't the best document to link to.

Comment: @UpTheCreek You can still initialize the connections on both of those using the options as shown. Both actually use the native driver under the hood.

Comment: @But I'm only connecting to mongos - does mongos ignore the server hash?

Comment: @UpTheCreek No it does not. Hence the clarification on the documentation which is talking about the difference of passing in a URL with hashed options or a Server configuration object. Most standard options are available. You need to scroll down that page and see what is excluded under the URL. But you can still define a server configuration instead.